# How to draw with a tap in Canvas?

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

This works ok if i move my finger, but if i just tap (From ACTION_DOWN to ACTION_UP without passing by the ACTION_MOVE) it won't draw anything. Any idea?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);   
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
        default:
        return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

The closest i have come up with an answer is to check if the eventx and y are the same than the last one at the ActionUP and add +1 in both x and y...

Answer (score 1):

To make it do something also on a simple tap you must do something like :

```
boolean notMoved = true;
switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
    return true;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        notMoved = false;
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if(notMoved) {
            //draw something
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        }
    break;
    default:
    return false;
}
```

Comment: adding path.line to ACTION_UP even in all cases did not solved the issue.

Comment: Since we don't know how the actual drawing is handled, that is just an example on how you should do it. Based on the code you provided...

Comment: the case is that in this snippet you are going to send the same eventX and eventY to the valitated tap case you are showing here, path.lineTo won't draw anything if the coords are the same, that is the issue i presented before, independent on how you make the drawing.

Answer (score 1):

... do something instead of nothing in your MotionEvent.ACTION_UP case. A something to start with:

```
if (moved) {
  moved = false;
  // on-tap behavior
}
```

Where the ACTION_MOVE case sets the flag. Your next step: make it easier to tap without accidentally 'moving' by having ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE share notes about coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
break;
```

instead of

```
return true;
```

Comment: this doesn't make sense, return true; is needed for onTouch return type... :S

Comment: but either way when it exits the switch, it will hit the return thats there, idk, just a suggestion